# How to do this projection in NHibernate?

Tags: database, nhibernate, queryover

I have these entities in my database

[image]

For a given `Job`, I want to basically get the results in the following form

```
<Translation>,<ExternalUnit.Text>,<ExternalTranslation.Text>
```

where the joining condition is that `Translation.Unit.Text == ExternalUnit.Text`

This is what I have so far, working fine:

```
var props = session.QueryOver<Translation>(() => translation)
            .Select(c => translation.Id, c => externalUnit.Text, c => externalTranslation.Text)
            .JoinAlias(() => translation.TranslationUnit, () => unit)                
            .JoinAlias(() => unit.Job, () => job)
            .Where(() => unit.Job == job)
            .JoinAlias(() => job.ExternalUnits, () => externalUnit)
            .JoinAlias(() => externalUnit.ExternalTranslations, () => externalTranslation)
            .Where(() => externalUnit.Text == unit.Text)
            .List<object[]>();

var translations = session.QueryOver<Translation>(() => translation)                
            .JoinAlias(() => translation.TranslationUnit, () => unit)                
            .JoinAlias(() => unit.Job, () => job)
            .Where(() => unit.Job == job)
            .JoinAlias(() => job.ExternalUnits, () => externalUnit)
            .JoinAlias(() => externalUnit.ExternalTranslations, () => externalTranslation)
            .Where(() => externalUnit.Text == unit.Text)
            .List<Translation>()
            .ToList();
```

Then I loop through `translations`, referring to `props`. However, I don't like this approach since I unnecessarily perform two (almost identical) queries to the database instead of just one.

But I can't get the desired projection working. I was thinking about something like this:

```
var data = session.QueryOver<Translation>(() => translationAlias)                
            .JoinAlias(() => translation.TranslationUnit, () => unit)                
            .JoinAlias(() => unit.Job, () => job)
            .Where(() => unit.Job == job)
            .JoinAlias(() => job.ExternalUnits, () => externalUnit)
            .JoinAlias(() => externalUnit.ExternalTranslations, () => externalTranslation)
            .Where(() => externalUnit.Text == unit.Text)
            .Select(() => translation, () => externalUnit.Text, () => externalTranslation.Text)
            .List()
```

but, obviously, NHibernate does not like the `Select(() => translation...)` bit (it does not allow me to project the whole entity).

Ideally I would like to select into anonymous types, like

```
var data = session.QueryOver<Translation>()
             ...
             .Select(() => new { A = translation, B = externalTranslation })
```

but I guess NHibernate is not there so far...

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it! NHibernate's LINQ provider saved me. What's great about it is that it can select into anonymous types, which makes joining so much easier. Just in case someone is curious, here it is for my particular case:

```
var q = 
(from c in
  (from b in            
    (from translation in session.Query<Translation>()
     join unit in units on translation.Unit equals unit
     where unit.Job == job
     select new { Translation = translation, Original = unit.Text })         
   join extUnit in externalUnits on job equals extUnit.Job
   where extUnit.Text == b.Original
   select new { Translation = b.Translation, ExternalUnit = extUnit })
 join extTranslation in extTranslations on c.ExternalUnit equals extTranslation.Unit
 select new { Translation = c.Translation, Suggestion = extTranslation })
 .ToList();
```

The SQL it generates is very reasonable, so I am pretty happy :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for this have shied away from linq provider but I can now see that it has moved forward alot.

Comment: @Rippo The funny thing is I also was asking the question on your own blog :-P http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/07/queryover-with-multiple-joins-into-dto.html